# Can I describe this circuit as a highpass filter?

Tags: filter

[image]

The input is square wave and the "filter" followed by two NOT gates. It's used to drive a bibolar transistor to reset an integrator(not shown).

I described this circuit to my professor as a highpass filter that responds only to the edges of the square input, followed by a buffer (2 not gate). I know that the gates convert the analog pulses to digital pulses but I don't know a suitable scientific name.

Anyway he told me that it's not a filter and the gates ain't a buffer (Actually he didn't even tell me what are they :D .)

Is that correct?

Comment: The CR circuit shown, where the time constant is much less than the square wave pulse length, is often called a 'differentiator' ie it produces an output proportional to the rate-of-change of the input.

Comment: @peterG But still, it's a kind of simple first order highpass filter, right?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiator#Passive_differentiator

Comment: The circuit is the same.  The usage is different.

Comment: "Filter" generally applies to a linear circuit, and this circuit is not remotely linear. A "high-pass filter" not only responds preferentially to a signal's frequency, its output amplitude responds proportionally to the input amplitude.  Your NOT gates will not do anything of the sort - they give a constant output amplitude regardless of input (to a first order). What you have is a high-pass filter followed by a limiter. If you replace the NOT gates by a unity-gain buffer, then you will have a high-pass filter.

Comment: If you're thinking of building this circuit physically, consider what the input to the first NOT gate will be when there is a falling edge on the input signal, and whether that's allowed by the Abs Max specs of your NOT gate.

Comment: @ThePhoton Even in simulation, it didn't work with the peak of the square wave= 5 V  because the inputs to the gates was very small, so I had to increase it to 12 V. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: @iMohaned, but at least in simulation it won't blow up your chips.

Comment: @TonyM "With a digital input and a digital output"  Depending on my understanding of your comment, you are treating the whole circuit as a block (digital input and digital output), But my thinking was to consider only the cap and the resistor as a filter which  blocks low freqencies(The constant portion of the wave) and passes high frequencies (The edges which contain much higher frequencies). I hope I clearified my point though it may be flawed.

Comment: The RC is a filter in the analog domain. But the two inverters are not part of the filter.

Comment: Professors teach, but some of them may be pedantic or play "dominance" games with students. Try to ignore the dominance and just accept the teaching as best you can. Most of the time there is no profit in conflict with a professor over minor issues.

Comment: @mkeith it's really disappointing, but I met too many of them that I got used to their pedantry..

Comment: @TonyM Nevermind :)